# Laravel 5.4 - how to find specific record in relation

Tags: php, laravel

I have some eloquent models named `Client` and `Company`. And my `Client` may belong to multiple `Company`:

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class);
}
```

I'd like to check if provided `Client` belongs to given `Company`. This is what I ended up with:

```
$client->companies
        ->filter(
            function ($value, $key) use ($company) {
                return $company->getKey() === $value->getKey();
            }
        )
        ->count() > 0;
```

Is there any shorter way?

Comment: do you need to load the entire relationship? do you need all those companies as models, or can this just be a db hit that determines existence?

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Alternatively you can check related model exist `$client->companies()->exists()`

Comment: @VasimVanzara Output should be true or false

Comment: @SaadSuri solution is perfect

Comment: @KarolSamborski `$client->companies()->exists()` will return boolean

Comment: @VasimVanzara that only checks if **any** relationship exists, not if a specific client belongs to a company

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using models and the relationship collection:

```
$client->companies->contains($company);
```

Using relationship query to check existence:

```
$client->companies()->where('company_id', $company->id)->exists();

// even shorter, and don't need to know about the key yourself

$client->companies()->whereKey($company)->exists();
```

Going form the other direction:

```
$company->clients->contains($client); // if setup
$company->clients()->where(....)->exists();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can always use your relationship method to query the relation:

```
$client->companies()->where('company_id', $company->id)->exists();
```

This uses the query builder to actually query the relation at the database level, unlike when you treat companies as a property which gets a collection of all of the related rows from the database.

Comment: i forget, can we use `whereKey($company)` instead of the full `where` there?

Comment: @lagbox, yes.  Looks like whereKey works from my testing.  You could update your answer to use that.

Comment: danke, ill just add an additional line for it ... just wanted to confirm

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$myArray = $client->companies->comp_id;
```

where `comp_id` can be any column name. This should return an array. Then check if the array is empty by doing:

```
if (empty($myArray))
```